# MySql does not start in XAMPP v3.2.1

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I use XAMPP v3.2.1 on window 8.1 system. Apache starts well but **MySql does not start.
Error Log below:**

```
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-08-14 08:38:22 17c0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is
DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option 
innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 

interlocked functions
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [ERROR] Aborting



2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Binlog end
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-08-14 08:38:22 6320 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean install of XAMPP?

Comment: Yes, I try everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow those steps, it worked for me:

1. exit Xampp server
2. go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3. delete the ibdata1 file
4. restart xampp server

Comment: This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies